# can't set default value for select with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, select

I'm trying to set a default value for `<select>` field data that is get with `$http`

View:

```
<select ng-options="dia for dia in ctrl.campos.dataNascimento.dias"  ng-model="ctrl.diaSelected></select>
<select ng-options="mes for mes in ctrl.campos.dataNascimento.meses" ng-model="ctrl.mesSelected"></select>
<select ng-options="ano for ano in ctrl.campos.dataNascimento.anos" ng-model="ctrl.anoSelected"></select>
```

Controller:

```
getData.userFacul().then(function(curriculo){
            var dataNascimento = perfilEstudante.curriculo.nascimento;
            dataNascimento = dataNascimento.split('-');

            perfilEstudante.mesSelected = campos.dataNascimento.meses[+dataNascimento[1]-1];
            perfilEstudante.diaSelected = campos.dataNascimento.dias[+dataNascimento[2]-1];
```

As `getData.userFacul()` is the $http request service.

I print the values on the view with `{{}}` and they show the correct values. The `select` boxes show all values, but the first one, which is default, is blank. Changin the option selected also changes the variables on the controller. I just don't understand why I cant set the default values of selectbox. When I try to set them Outside of the $http request, it works though.
Any ideas?

EDIT: I made some tests, and for some reason when I declare the ng-models of the selectboxes inside a $http request, these values aren't set as default on the view. However, outside the $http request it works.

Comment: are you trying to set a default value as the first item for the http response or some something like -- Select -- default value?

Comment: I'm trying to set the response of $http as default values on the selectbox.

Comment: if there is still an issue, a plunker would help understanding whats going on

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Angular *doesn't know you have updated the value* and so doesn't perform a *digest*. In order to 'notify' Angular that a property has changed you can use the `$scope.$apply()` method. Like so:

```
getData.userFacul().then(function(curriculo){
    var dataNascimento = perfilEstudante.curriculo.nascimento;
    dataNascimento = dataNascimento.split('-');

        perfilEstudante.mesSelected = campos.dataNascimento.meses[+dataNascimento[1]-1];
    perfilEstudante.diaSelected = campos.dataNascimento.dias[+dataNascimento[2]-1];
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: *"getData.userFacul() is the $http request service"* - so digest is infact triggered.

Comment: I tried adding `$scope.$apply`, but it outputs the error "$digest already in progress".