# ng-model gets defaulted correctly, but select won't show the text, shows blank instead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile, ng-options

So, I'm trying to read a list of options from the server, and supply it to  tag, with the first option as default - which is really important thing to do - but all I've got is the model is being set correctly, but in the select it shows blank!, and I have no idea why is that!

I've tried a lot of SO soulations, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439460/cant-set-default-value-for-select-with-ng-model), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866656/select-wont-show-default-value-when-list-is-read-from-server-angularjs).

view:-

```
<select ng-options="option as option.Name for option in options track by option.ID" ng-model="selected">
```

controller:-

```
DataService.getOptionsFromServer().then(function (result) {
    //console.log(result.data);
    $scope.options = result.data;
    $scope.selected = $scope.options[0];
    console.log($scope.selected);
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

the

```
console.log($scope.selected);
```

shows that the selected is being set correctly!
any help?

**Update1:** Seems the problems is compatibility between angular and jquery-mobile (not added by me :@), anybody knows something about that?

**Update2:** when removing *jquery.mobile.min.js*, it works fine. unfortunately, I need it throw out the project.

**Update3:** the problem is that JQM produce a span to display the value selected, and that's the problem!, I've binded the select, not the span.
the problem is that I can't bind the span till now, 'cuase JQM generate the span in the runtime :( , that's why when commenting out the JQM js it works fine.

**Updated4:** solved :D, solution given below for future reference.

Comment: can you try using ng-init=”selected”?

Comment: I recreated a fiddle and it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11726/

Comment: Seems to work fine, also when loading the options asynchronously: https://jsfiddle.net/t2g15fjy/

Comment: @Matheno I've seen the fiddles, but it won't work into my project, do you think it might be related to the project being Cordova project?!

Comment: @devqon I've seen the fiddles, but it won't work into my project, do you think it might be related to the project being Cordova project?!

Comment: @TudorGrigoriu I don't get what you are saying, can you explain a bit more :) ?

Comment: @Matheno which angular js did you use?

Comment: This was created in Angular 1.4. Notice that I did delete the 'track by option.ID'

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.4.7, and removed that part too, still nothing.

Comment: @Matheno I've updated the Question, can you give it a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that JQM doesn't display the selected value itself, instead it gets the selected value, and put into a span in run time, and then hides the select completely, trust me, it took me > 12 hours to learn it the hard way!

so in order for JQM to re-get the selected value from the select and send it to displaying span, you have to call:

```
jQuery("#SelectId").selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

notice that in case you're using angular like me, it's better to use "jQuery" not "$" to avoid conflict between angular and jQuery.

don't take that one line solation lightly :D, it cost more than a working day to get it :D, hope it would be helpful :D .

importent ref: [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/dynamically-changing-select-value-of-jquery-mobile-select-box/).

also note: you can make an angular directive if you intend to use the select more than once :D .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not getting any data from the server ,can you check that?

Comment: not true, as can see the in the code

//console.log(result.data);

I've tested the data.

Comment: Can you maybe change the name of the $scope variable from $scope.options to $scope.items and change the corresponding code in the select tag?